# How do I dynamically generate a unique name for each option within an options_from_collection_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to generate an option tag like this:

```
<option name="option_1" value="1">Small</option>
<option name="option_2" value="2">Medium</option>
```

Using my call like this:

```
<%= select_tag option.name, options_from_collection_for_select(option.option_values, "id", "name"), include_blank: true %>
```

Gets me half-way there, by generating this:

```
<option value="1">Small</option>
<option value="2">Medium</option>
```

How do I add the `name` attribute to the option tag, using this structure? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select_tag option.name, options_for_select(option.option_values.map{ |o| [o.name, o.id, {:name_or_smth_else => "option_#{o.id}"}] })
```

[options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

Answer (score 1):

The option tag doesn't have a `name` attribute. The `name` attribute should be defined in the `select` tag:

```
<select name="name">
  <option value="1">Small</option>
  <option value="2">Medium</option>
</select>
```

See this page for more info - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: So...how do I uniquely identify each option? Any way to do that?

Comment: Hrmm...looks like it can allow for a `label` attribute - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_label.asp How do I do that with that rails helper?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the `value` attribute? If the `value` attribute is a model id, then it will be unique.

Comment: Do you want to identify using javascript or jQuery? The selector would be `$("select option[value='1']");` for jQuery.

Comment: The thing is that there will be multiple select menus on this one page, with multiple options having the same value. So I have to have a unique way to identify each `option`. On another note though, how would I select, using jQuery, the `selected` option (after a user has chosen the value they want)?

Comment: `$('select#the_id option:selected')` would select the selected `option`