# How to add a data-attribute to each option of my select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-data-attribute

In my Rails app I have this select box:

```
<%= f.select :invoice_id, current_user.invoices.numbers_ordered %>
```

This is my `Invoice` class:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  def self.numbers_ordered
    order(:number).map { |i| [ i.number, i.id ] }
  end

  ...

end
```

How can I add a `data-attribute` to each option without changing too much of my existing code?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15382504/1044646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
def self.numbers_ordered
  order(:number).map { |i| [ i.number, i.id, :'data-attribute' => i.some_data ] }
end
```

`select` uses `options_for_select` inside and takes all the parameters for `options_for_select`.

See Rails API for [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select), and the [comment in options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select#1030-helpers-using-options-for-select)

Comment: Thanks. It was easier than I thought. I had to use this syntax to get it working though: `:'data-attribute'`

Comment: oh. yes. I think `-` is not allowed in symbols without wrapping in quotes. I will edit that.

Comment: With modern versions of ruby and rails, I think you can also do this:  `data: { attribute: i.some_data}`

Comment: @DGM. wont `data: { attribute: i.some_data}` convert to `:data => {:attribute => i.some_data}` ? and I think new syntax of hash will be an error in case of something like this `{data-attribute: i.some_data}`

Comment: yes, those are the same hashes, but with different notations... but rails will take the hash with the data key and turn it into `data-attribute=foo`  see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

Answer (score 1):

This explains it very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076805/2036529

In your view, you can use:

```
<%= f.select :invoice_id, options_for_select(current_user.invoices.numbers_ordered) %>
```

and in your Invoice class, change the method to following:

```
def self.numbers_ordered
   order(:number).map { |i| [ i.number, i.id, {'data-customAttr': "#{i.attr_1} -- #{i.attr_2}" ] }
end
```